# Android Studio (Kotlin): after rename, auto-import keeps looking for old names

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, auto-import

I've built an app based on some tutorial code, so its name was `com.example.gamefoo`.  Then I decided to replace the "example" by my name, so I changed it to `com.myname.gamefoo`.
I couldn't get the refactor function to do it for me, so I ended up closing Studio and doing the rename manually with regular text-edit functions from the command line.  I made sure to replace all occurrences, and I also deleted all the build subdirectories.
However, Studio still does not understands the line

```
import com.myname.gamefoo.databinding.FragmentAboutBinding
```

and if I allow auto-import, it adds instead the old version, with `example`, which is nowhere to be found in my project:

```
import com.example.gamefoo.databinding.FragmentAboutBinding
```

I believe that this class is auto-generated from the `navigation.xml`, which does not mention `com.example` now.  I tried to clean and rebuild several times but this issue persists.

At this point, I don't even understand, from where does Studio pick up the name `com.example.gamefoo` ?  The string `com.example` is nowhere to be found in my project directories -- not in any code, xml or config files!

Is there a way to do a "deep clean" to make Studio forget the old name?

Comment: The packages in Android are taken by folder name so com is a folder that contains example that is a folder that contains gamefoo and on and on until you get to your class name. So if you only changed the text but not the folder names the issue will persist. I think it's easier to just start a new project and copy the code over there.

Comment: Thanks.  I did change the folder name, the issue was elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

After re-reading the [page on View Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) I checked and noticed that I did not have `viewBinding=true` in my `gradle.build` file.  This is very strange!  I must have had it there at some point, because my code worked before the name change.

I put that line back, and now the build works, and auto-import is not confused anymore!

So I suppose the story is, the `Binding` classes were kept around (but where?) from the last time that I had `viewBinding=true`, and since that line was missing, they stuck around but didn't get refreshed.